# Regex to match numbers and periods within quotes

Tags: json, regex

I will admit I am new to regex but i cant figure this one out.

I am trying to regex the "tag_name" contents to grab the numbers and peroids only from the github api so i can manage and track versioning though my python app. They appear like this when accessing the api / json;

```
 "tag_name": "jenkins-docker-packaging-2.235.1",
```

When i use the regex;

```
\"tag_name\":\s\"(\S+(\S.*))\",
```

I would like to grab the numbers and peroids only, but it only matches the 1 at the end like this;

[Screen capture of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLU6v.png)

Which has me stumped because i thought the (\S.*) group would capture any character while being greedy.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a JSON parser to extract the `tag_name` value, then extract the numbers from the value.

Comment: Refer to this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FvSuZB/1)

Comment: @Abra thanks for that it does work, but how would i incorporate the "tag_name" string?

Comment: Refer to what @TimBiegeleisen suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73160951/regex-to-match-numbers-and-periods-within-quotes#comment129211124_73160951).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I ended up using your method. There were too many inconsistent lines not being matched or getting wrong matches as there is no naming standard. JSON matching was the one that worked every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with "tag_name" and get the [0-9.] after -

```
^"tag_name".*\-([0-9.]+)
```